# Adding a joomla hits counter for a component

Tags: joomla, pageviews

I have joomla 3.4, and I have installed a component for projects management, I need to install the hits counter (like in joomla article hits) to view how many time each project page has been loaded.

Can you please help me!

Comment: can you please provide more technical information about your problem? do you have an issue installing the plugin? is there an error?

Comment: Which project management component is it a custom one or prebuilt Joomla extension.

Comment: The plugin is correctly installed and it works well, but this plugin don't include a hits counter, i need to add it.

the component is joombri.in